# RegEx vscode - replace decimal places and round correctly

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace

Is it possible to use regex to round decimal places?

I have lines that look like this but without any spaces (space added for readability).

```
0,      162.3707542,   -162.3707542
128.2,  151.8299471,   -23.62994709 // this 151.829 should lead to 151.83
```

I want to remove all numbers after the second decimal position and if possible round the second decimal position based on the third position.

```
0,      162.37,   -162.37
128.2,  151.82,   -23.62     // already working .82
...,    151.83,   ...     // intended .83 <- this is my question
```

#### What is working

The following regex ([see this sample on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DKZ0ai/1)) almost does what i want

```
 ([0-9]+\.)([0-9]{2})(\d{0,}) // search
 $1$2                         // replace
```

#### My understanding

The search works like this

1. group: `([0-9]+\.)` find 1 up to n numbers and a point
2. group: `([0-9]{2})` followd by 2 numbers
3. group: `(\d{0,})` followed by 0 or more numbers / digits

[image: RegEx mapped groups]

In [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) in the replacement field only group 1 and 2 are referenced `$1$2`.

[image: Visual Studio Code Search and replace with RegEx]

This  [results in this substitution](https://regex101.com/r/DKZ0ai/1) (regex101.com)

[image: Replacement / Substitution]

#### Question

Is it possible to change the last digit of `$2` (group two) based on the first digit in `$3` (group three) ?

My intention is to round correctly. In the sample above this would mean

```
151.8299471 // source
151.82      // current result
151.83      // desired result 2 was changed to 3 because of third digit 9
```

Comment: Not sure if it is even possible (I guess not?) since it's not what regular expressions are meant to do at all. What if you would have `3.996`. You'd need some post-processing to understand this is now `4.00` right?

Comment: I have not thought of this. Yes to be consistent this should become 4.00. But i could live that only numbers  8 and lower will be rounded up. So `3.986` would be converted to `3.99` but `3.996` could be truncated to `3.99`.

Comment: Even so, building this logic into a pattern isn't possible AFAIK.

Comment: This may be possible with an extension I wrote for finding and replacing that allows you to write javascript in the replace, let me work on it.  Extension is `Find and Transform`.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I thought, once I found the `Number.toFixed(2)` method.

Using this extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), make this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",               // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": "(-?[0-9]+\\.\\d{3,})",  // only need the whole number as one capture group
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",             // starting wrapper to indicate a js operation begins
            
        "return $1.toFixed(2);",  // $1 from the find regex
      
      "}$$"             // ending wrapper to indicate a js operation ends
    ],

    // or simply in one line
    // "replace":  "$${ return $1.toFixed(2); }$$",
    
    "isRegex": true
  },
}
```

[The empty lines above are there just for readability.]

This could also be put into a setting, see the README, so that a command appears in the Command Palette with the title of your choice.

Also note that javascript rounds `-23.62994709` to `-23.63`.  You had `-23.62` in your question, I assume `-23.63` is correct.

[image: round to 2 decimal digits demo with regex find]

---

If you do want to truncate things like `4.00` to `4` or `4.20` to `4.2` use this `replace` instead.

```
"replace": [
  "$${",
            
    "let result = $1.toFixed(2);",
    "result = String(result).replace(/0+$/m, '').replace(/\\.$/m, '');",
    "return result;",
      
  "}$$"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not only that you need to update the digit of `$2`. if the number is `199.995` you have to modify all digits of your result.

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen).

You can use a predefined set of regex's.

```
  "regexTextGen.predefined": {
    "round numbers": {
      "originalTextRegex": "(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)",
      "generatorRegex": "{{=N[1]:fixed(2):simplify}}"
    }
  }
```

With the same regex `(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)` in the VSC Find dialog select all number you want, you can use **Find in Selection** and `Alt+Enter`.

Then execute the command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression**.

Select the predefined option and press Enter a few times. You get a preview of the result, you can escape the UI and get back the original text.

In the process you can edit **generatorRegex** to change the number of decimals or to remove the **`simplify`**.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to round-off decimal numbers correctly using regular expressions.

We need basically this regex:

```
secondDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{1})[\d]/g; // roun-off digit
thirdDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{2})[\d]/g; // first discard digit
isNonZeroAfterThirdDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{3,})[1-9]/g;
isOddSecondDD_regx = /[13579]/g;
```

Full code (round-off digit up to two decimal places):

```
const uptoOneDecimalPlaces_regx = /[\+\-\d]*\.[\d]{1}/g;
const secondDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{1})[\d]/g;
const thirdDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{2})[\d]/g;
const isNonZeroAfterThirdDD_regx = /(?<=[\d]*\.[\d]{3,})[1-9]/g;
const num =  '5.285';
const uptoOneDecimalPlaces = num.match(uptoOneDecimalPlaces_regx)?.[0];
const secondDD = num.match(secondDD_regx)?.[0];
const thirdDD = num.match(thirdDD_regx)?.[0];
const isNonZeroAfterThirdDD = num.match(isNonZeroAfterThirdDD_regx)?.[0];
const isOddSecondDD = /[13579]/g.test(secondDD);
// check carry
const carry = !thirdDD ? 0 : thirdDD > 5 ? 1 : thirdDD < 5 ? 0 : isNonZeroAfterThirdDD ? 1 : isOddSecondDD ? 1 : 0;
let roundOffValue;
if(/9/g.test(secondDD) && carry) {
  roundOffValue = (Number(`${uptoOneDecimalPlaces}` + `${secondDD ? Number(secondDD) : 0}`) + Number(`0.0${carry}`)).toString();
} else {
  roundOffValue = (uptoOneDecimalPlaces + ((secondDD ? Number(secondDD) : 0) + carry)).toString();
}
// Beaufity output : show exactly 2 decimal places if output is x.y or x
const dd = roundOffValue.match(/(?<=[\d]*[\.])[\d]*/g)?.toString().length;
roundOffValue = roundOffValue + (dd=== undefined ? '.00' : dd === 1 ? '0' : '');
console.log(roundOffValue);
```

For more details check: [Round-Off Decimal Number properly using Regular Expression](https://medium.com/@artbindu/round-off-decimal-number-properly-using-regular-expression-1225d42239fb)